# What is the correct syntax for meta description in html

Tags: html, meta-tags

Is there a difference between <meta description="blahblahblah"> and <meta name="description" content="blahblahblah">?

Are they both valid? Is one obsolete (or deprecated)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meta element does not accept the attribute "description". You should always use the `name=""` & `content=""` attributes in this case (and many other meta tags) to keep it valid.

Source: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML#metadata_the_meta_element)

Answer (score 0):

The `meta description` doesn't exist. The whole bunch of meta tags in your document head can be considered for Meta description.